# How to create a backslash fraction using sfrac

Tags: fractions, xfrac

I tried to create a backslash fraction using sfrac, but the output looks like this:
[image: sfrac attempt]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xfrac}

\begin{document}

$ \sfrac{A}[\backslash]{B} $

\end{document}
```

Any idea how can I fix this? (A should be under B)

Comment: Try `\newcommand*{\backfrac}[2]{\reflectbox{\sfrac{\reflectbox{\(#2\)}}{\reflectbox{\(#1\)}}}}` and then `\(\backfrac{A}{B}\)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it, first reflect a normal `\sfrac` and then reflect both arguments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\newcommand*{\backfrac}[2]{\reflectbox{\sfrac{\reflectbox{\(#2\)}}{\reflectbox{\(#1\)}}}}
\begin{document}
    \(\backfrac{A}{B}\)
\end{document}
```

The result is
[image]